# Meta Slider Lite plugin shortcode in post not working

Tags: footer, slideshow

I'm trying to implement a slider in my Wordpress post. For this I'm using `Meta Slider` plugin. When I've added a slider, I should be able to use the shortcode in my posts (`[metaslider id=21]`). If I add this to one of my post, it shows up the same way on the live page. I don't see any slider, there is just a string "[metaslider id=21]" on my page.

I checked that `wp_footer();` is implemented right before the `body` tag is ending and that the footer is implemented in every php file.

I get the post content using this way:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'tag' => get_the_title());
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $wp_query->get_posts();

foreach($posts as $post){
    $id = $post->ID;
    $content = get_post($id);

    echo $content->post_content;
}
```

It gets the content perfectly but it's not loading the slider.

Can someone please tell me the reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the content through `do_shortcode()` - at the moment you're just echo'ing the raw post content, so nothing gets parsed.

```
echo do_shortcode( $content->post_content );
```

However, you might be better off implementing a proper "[loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)" and using `the_content()` template tag - doing so will ensure everything runs "as normal" (firing all the typical hooks and formatting filters), accommodating for any quirks/extra hooks your slider plugin might rely on:

```
while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    $posts->the_post();
    the_content();
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore the global post to the "current" post
```